# Emails that forward back to us from external SMTP server

Tags: postfix, mail

I have a Mail server (FQDN: mail.ours.com) using Postfix and Dovecot, users having email address like user@ours.com. Like many others SMTP server, if user claim that they are from @ours.com, they need to pass sasl or should be in mynetwork parameter according to the restriction setting; so if user do not pass sasl and not having the ip address in mynetwork, they may got some error message like “sender not login”.

The situation is when a user amy@ours.com want to send email to bob@external.com, but Bob do the setting to let his email forward to bob@ours.com. So SMTP server from external.com will interact with ours SMTP server and claim that the sender is from amy@ours.com wanted to send mail to bob@ours.com. After the request, SMTP from external.com will receive the error message from ours SMTP server said that “(amy@ours.com) sender not login”, and Amy will finally got this bounce error message.

I have no idea how to deal with this situation, very appreciate if anyone can give me the solution or leave some comment, thanks.

Comment: I have never encountered a mail server that was configured in that way. It looks like you are trying to (poorly) reinvent SPF/DKIM...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, can you kindly tell me more detail about your reply. I'm not trying to block any client from our mail server, i think it's reasonable to reject someone who claim that he is valid user in our mail domain but cannot prove his identity. (Because mail server from external.com cannot prove that she is amy@ours.com, so our mail server reject the request with "sender not login", but if she is amy@others.com, everything will be fine), thanks again for the reply!

Comment: That's exactly what DKIM is for; look into it.

Comment: Thanks again for the comment, but DKIM seem not work for the situation I encounter.

Below is the process
1. amy@ours.com want to send email to bob@external.com
2. BOB(bob@external.com) "forward" the mail to bob@ours.com
3. external SMTP server make the request to ours SMTP server (MAIL FROM: amy@ours.com, RCPT TO: bob@ours.com)
4. ours SMTP server reject the request according to the setting(reject_sender_login_mismatch in smtpd_sender_restrictions) with Error Message(<amy@ours.com> sender not login)

How can I accept this request make by external SMTP server.
Very Thanks!

Comment: The point is that since the mail would be properly DKIM-signed, your server should accept it regardless of where it comes from. `smtp_server_restrictions` is not the proper mechanism for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, but even if the mail can pass DKIM check, it still need to pass the restrictions(I cannot find any setting to let 'DKIM pass mail' skip the smtp restrictions), so the mail will still blocked with or without DKIM. "reject_sender_login_mismatch" need sender to pass the auth(sasl) and need auth user name match the one in MAIL FROM address if the request MAIL FROM address is end with ours domain(@ours.com). We need this to avoid fake sender. Thanks for the response.